# $100\frac{dp}{dt}=p(100-p)$, find $p(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So far what I have done:

- Recognised this is a separable ODE
- Rearranged into the form

$$100\int\frac1{p(100-p)}\ dp=\int1\ dt$$

However I am not sure how to proceed from here, I am having trouble integrating the LHS of the equation. Whatever I get seems too messy to isolate $p$ to find $c$.

Comment: For future reference, this is a rescaled version of the [logistic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function#Logistic_differential_equation).

Comment: You have $1000$ in the title, but the rearranged form has $100$. Which do you mean?

Comment: I mean 100 my bad

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{p(100-p)}=\frac{1}{100}\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{100-p}\right)$$

Each term can be integrated separately.

Comment: Okay that helped me with the integration, however, I am not sure how to proceed to find p(t).

I have: 100p-p^2=A*e^t, A=e^+-C

Comment: I thought the issue was with integration. This query of yours has been nicely addressed in Fourier Transform's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do the integrals:

$$100\left(-\frac{1}{100}\ln(100 - p) + \frac{1}{100}\ln(p)\right) = t$$

Or, if you want to include the extrema, thence from $p_0$ to $p$ and from $t_0$ to $t$ you get:

$$100\left[\left(-\frac{1}{100}\ln(100 - p) + \frac{1}{100}\ln(p)\right) - \left(-\frac{1}{100}\ln(100 - p_0) + \frac{1}{100}\ln(p_0)\right)\right] = t - t_0$$

Now it's a matter of arranging things and get $p$. Can you do it?

In case, here it is:

$$-\ln(100-p) + \ln(p) + \ln(100 - p_0) - \ln(p_0) = t - t_0$$

Using the properties of logarithm

$$\ln\left(\frac{p(100 - p_0)}{p_0 (100 - p)}\right) = t - t_0$$

Exponentiating

$$\frac{p(100 - p_0)}{p_0(100 - p)} = e^{t - t_0}$$

$$p(100 - p_0) = e^{t - t_0}(p_0(100 - p)) = 100p_0e^{t - t_0} - pp_0e^{t - t_0}$$

Hence

$$p(100 - p_0 + p_0e^{t - t_0}) = 100p_0 e^{t - t_0}$$

$$p(t) = \frac{100p_0 e^{t - t_0}}{100 - p_0 + p_0e^{t - t_0}}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow how you go that, could you please explain the steps

Comment: @rra117 I simply integrated. You have to fix the extrema of the integration so you have

$$100 \int_{p_0}^p\ \frac{\text{d}p}{p(100 - p)} = \int_{t_0}^t\ 1\ \text{d}t$$

Then solve the integrals!

Comment: I see, sorry for not understanding but why do we set these extrema and what determines them? I haven't learned how to do this questions like this!

Comment: @rra117 You fix the extrema for correctness. You have to integrate from an initial point to a final one, and from an initial time to a final time. Without extrema you would get simply:

$$\ln\left(\frac{p}{100-p}\right) = t$$

So exponentiating you get

$$\frac{p}{100 - p} = e^t$$

And taking the reciprocal:

$$\frac{100 - p}{p} = e^{-t}$$

From which 

$$\frac{100}{p} = e^{-t} + 1$$

$$p(t) = \frac{1}{100}\left(e^{-t} + 1\right)^{-1}$$

Hence

$$p(t) = \frac{1}{100}\frac{e^t}{1 + e^t}$$

Comment: @rra117 As you can see, those are general extrema. $p_0$ it's like the initial point $p$ at time zero, to say so, and $p$ is the final state $p$ at time $t$. It's all algebraical, no values.

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $p(t)$ when $\text{n}$ and $\text{m}$ are constants:

$$\text{n}\cdot p'(t)=p(t)\cdot\left(\text{m}-p(t)\right)\Longleftrightarrow\frac{\text{n}\cdot p'(t)}{p(t)\cdot\left(\text{m}-p(t)\right)}=1\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{\text{n}\cdot p'(t)}{p(t)\cdot\left(\text{m}-p(t)\right)}\space\text{d}t=\int1\space\text{d}t$$

Now use:

1. $$\int1\space\text{d}t=t+\text{C}$$
2. Substitute $u=p(t)$ and $\text{d}u=p'(t)\space\text{d}t$:
   $$\int\frac{\text{n}\cdot p'(t)}{p(t)\cdot\left(\text{m}-p(t)\right)}\space\text{d}t=\text{n}\int\frac{1}{u\left(\text{m}-u\right)}\space\text{d}u=\text{n}\left[\int\frac{1}{\text{m}u}\space\text{d}u-\int\frac{1}{\text{m}u-\text{m}^2}\space\text{d}u\right]$$
3. $$\int\frac{1}{\text{m}u}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{\text{m}}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=\frac{\ln\left|u\right|}{\text{m}}+\text{C}=\frac{\ln\left|p(t)\right|}{\text{m}}+\text{C}$$
4. Substitute $s=\text{m}u-\text{m}^2$ and $\text{d}s=\text{m}\space\text{d}u$:
   $$\int\frac{1}{\text{m}u-\text{m}^2}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{\text{m}}\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}s=\frac{\ln\left|s\right|}{\text{m}}+\text{C}=\frac{\ln\left|\text{m}\cdot p(t)-\text{m}^2\right|}{\text{m}}+\text{C}$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{m}}\cdot\left(\ln\left|p(t)\right|-\ln\left|\text{m}\cdot p(t)-\text{m}^2\right|\right)=t+\text{C}$$

---

So, in your problem when $\text{n}=1000$ and $\text{m}=100$, we get:

$$-10\ln\left(\frac{100|p(t)-10|}{|p(t)|}\right)=t+\text{C}$$